# Youtube livestreaming a prerecorded video

Tags: youtube-api, streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

I need to create a live event with specific dates and scheduled times on Youtube. The content itself is pre-recorded video, but I want to showcase it in a "live" manner so that users can't skip ahead. After each individual live event comes to a finish, I then want the video to be archived so users can freely watch it on our youtube channel.

Any help or info would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to do it via youtube itself ? If yes, then you will have to enable "Live" streaming feature in your account. Looks like you will have to be eligible to have it enabled.

http://www.youtube.com/live/all

If its enables, you can push your pre-recorded video files to the google's publishing point. For that you can use any supported media encoders. More info can be read here on how to set it up.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2907883?hl=en&ref_topic=2853713

Once thats setup, you can stream events as if its a real live event !

Comment: I tried out the encoder as you suggested and it works! Saved me a lot of time figuring this out. Thanks Aby!!